# Excel "Average" based on variable term

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to create a formula that averages values based on a variable term so its a variable average based on the term. Not sure what formula to use (or approach to take). Say I have 5 values
1,010,000,
1,004,344,
998,720,
993,127,
987,565...
I know the average over a 5 years term is 998,751 kWh. What formula can I use if I want to change the term 3yrs, or 4 yrs (or in the real case that I am working on) .. Tried an =Average(B6:(B6+"variable years in the term cell)) ..
Appreciate any help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you provide a sample table?

Answer (score 1):

So, if I'm understanding correctly, you have a list of values; you want to average a subset of them; and you want to control the size of that subset using another cell.

Assume our sheet is laid out like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1010000 | 1 | ?Formula? |
| 1004344 |  |  |
| 998720 |  |  |
| 993127 |  |  |
| 987565 |  |  |

Where our values are in A, the number of values to include is in B, and the average is in C.

We can use the `OFFSET` function to return a variably-sized range of cells, based on the value in another cell. `OFFSET` has three required arguments and two optional arguments: Reference, Rows, Cols, Height, and Width.

Reference is the starting cell of the range. Rows is the number of rows to move down from the reference cell. Cols is the number of columns to move to the right of the starting cell. Height is the number of rows to return. Width is the number of columns to return. If Height or Width are ommitted, it will assume the return is the same as the number of cells in the reference.

So in our case, we would use this formula: `=AVERAGE(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,$B$1,1))`

This formula starts at cell `A1`; moves down 0 rows, moves right 0 columns - that is, it starts from the reference cell. It then returns the number of rows entered in cell B1, and 1 column. These are handed to the Average function to return the result. Changing the value in B1 will change the number of rows being returned.

If the value in B1 is 0 or absent, you will get a `#REF!` error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of values is in A1, the formula to use is:

```
=AVERAGE(B6:OFFSET(B6,0,VALUE(A1)-1))
```